# How do I tell coworkers about my pronouns?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, gender

I'm genderfluid, and I use xe/xem as my default pronouns. Other pronouns, such as he/him or she/her, are not always wrong for me but my preference varies, so I prefer not to put them anywhere semi-permanent.

I don't like using they/them because it often feels impersonal: they're just using it as the default; it feels like people don’t actually know my pronouns.

I started a new job this week. Creating an "about me"/profile is optional, so I skipped it during onboarding, though I can always go back and add one later. However, I did put in my preferred name -- even though it's unrelated to my legal name, my coworkers accepted it without any questions.

So far, they've assumed I use he/him. I can't exactly blame them for that assumption, but I haven't corrected them yet. I have no idea how they feel about neopronouns or whether they would respect my pronoun preference.

**How can I disclose my pronouns in a professional manner?** And **what should I consider** before doing so?

Additional information:

- None of the documents I received even mention pronouns, and the only place that gender is mentioned is in the harassment & discrimination policy.
- The company has a set email signature format, which does not include pronouns.
- Some of my coworkers have set their pronouns in Slack, but many haven't. Regardless, it doesn't show up when you mouse over someone's name -- you have to click on their name to see their full profile, and it only appears there.

Comment: FYI - "Should I bring it up" isn't really answerable.  I've answered this from the point of view of "Is it professional to bring it up", which is slightly different, but the closest thing we can answer here. You may wish to edit your question to reflect that.  Also, see the [faq] and the [help] for more information on how questions are best written here.  Thanks!!

Comment: Can you maybe add a country tag and tell us what your company's HR policy says about it? Are your pronouns a known and accepted policy, or completely new and unsupported?

Comment: "I don't like using they/them because it often feels impersonal: they're just using it as the default; it feels like people don’t actually know my pronouns." I've added this based upon the linked comment in chat (note chat can be deleted). Sorry if I have not conveyed an accurate meaning.

Comment: @nvoigt Added [tag:united-states]. I don't know what, if any, official policy exists off the top of my head, but I can try to look for one today. I've seen one internal document that refers to the reader as "he" (as opposed to "they" or "he/she"), but I've also been told that that document is outdated, so that may not reflect current practice.

Comment: @keshlam I do actually own such a pin, I just haven’t worn it to work (yet).

Comment: Your question is on 4 close votes and I'd recommend editing it to something more answerable as @Joe already mentioned. You could rephrase it to "what should I consider before disclosing my pronouns", "how can I determine how supportive my workplace would be", or simply focus on how to announce them professionally (and perhaps deal with less-than-kind reactions if you were to get them). The phrase "should I?" is a bit of a close vote magnet. :)

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks for the warning, I’ll edit it now.

Comment: @Lilienthal Is this better? I'll gladly edit it again if not, I'm just not sure how to best word it.

Comment: Looks fine, main thing was to check whether you had a specific focus in mind but this is general enough and doesn't read like "make my mind up for me". I've edited your post somewhat to bold the key questions and remove the "edit" metadata. I've also changed "bring it up" to "disclose" since I'm guessing that's your goal and you don't necessarily want to do it in person / in conversation (as "bring it up" can imply).

Comment: @bbrk24 For the uninitiated,  how does one pronounce xe and xem?

Comment: @nuggethead There are audio samples at https://en.pronouns.page/xe , and IPA pronunciations if you understand that.

Answer (score 45):

> I don't like using they/them because it often feels impersonal: they're just using it as the default; it feels like people don’t actually know my pronouns.

It's important to note here that a workplace, while respectful, is not meant to feel personal. Often impersonal communication is desirable, as it's direct and to the point. If they/them is impersonal to you, then those words are doing their job. It's not conveying information about your gender (or genders in your case), in places where it is not important.

Hopefully workers will respect your gender fluidity, because at the end of the day, it's of no professional interest to their job. Where you will have friction is attempting to impose language on your coworkers, which adds a mental burden on them, and is distracting.

Many people will use gender-neutral language where possible as a default, you have to determine if you want to impose your will on those people and insist they speak in a style of speaking that you find sufficiently personal.

As an example, I've used a gender-neutral pronoun nine times above to refer to you. I have no idea what the pronouns should have been in such a case using your pronoun scheme. But it is of little consequence to the information I wish to convey.

I suspect the most reasonable course of action is to ask for them/they pronouns in an official capacity, and save the neopronouns for discussions with those that take an active interest in your gender.

Comment: I added a link to an explanation, feel free to revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: +1 for the gender-neutral approach, and explaining why the business settings may favour that. A really important and often forgotten aspect.

Comment: In practice, it's very variable and this general rule may not apply. Some workplaces are very keen to accommodate diversity and will gladly welcome any pronouns while others will ignore you (and it's often not the obvious companies - defence companies for some reason seem to think that certificates for diversity makes up for killing people).

Comment: I just added the actual clicky link, the "XY Answer" wording is the original. It is a bit of "SO-slang" if you want to call it that, I don't feel it's inappropriate. I just added the link in case the term "XY Problem" is unknown.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I've removed the line. I was hoping to identify that I was not directly addressing the question posed, but instead elaborating on a side point.

Comment: -1 because this is a non-answer. Using they/them may make the conversation easier, but I still have to express that I would prefer they/them over he/him somehow, and this fails to answer how.

Comment: @Bbrk24 wait, so what pronouns do you actually want used? I got the strong impression from your post that you are against the they/them.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul To be perfectly clear: I disprefer what this answer suggests, but it would still be better than the current situation. I would be okay with people continuing to use he/she/they as long as they respect my fluctuating preference, but communicating what that is seems like it would be annoying for everyone involved. Ideally, my coworkers would respect that I use xe/xem, but I recognize that may not actually happen.

Comment: @Bbrk24 the reality is that with something that keeps changing in an unpredictable way; you cannot realistically expect everyone to follow. It's simply not feasible, and undue burden on others. What part of this answer do you disagree with though? Is it that you'd rather have "Xe/xem" instead of "They/Them" and used it at all times, or is it something else about this answer that you disagree with?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Yes, I would prefer xe/xem over they/them.

Comment: @Bbrk24 could you then update and simply the question to just that, excluding the unnecessary details, if all that is about it just "how to get people at work to use Xe/Xem pronouns", the suggestion of wanting variability and then disliking them/they is probably what throws people off, sure did me.

Comment: I don't think the answer is appropriate, as it ignores the preferences given by OP. Pronouns are, to some people, very important, and using "they/them" to refer to someone that you *don't know the pronouns of* is fine, but if you *do* know the pronouns, it's disrespectful.

Comment: @Joe That's your opinion. But people use gender-neutral pronouns all the time. Personally, I don't see how not dotting a conversation with the gender preference of someone is disrespectful.

Comment: Gender neutral pronouns are appropriate when you don't know the gender of someone.  They're inappropriate if you *do* know the gender of that person.

Comment: @Joe That's your opinion. Personally, I don't think we need to continually specify the  gender or genders of people when speaking. And provided people are consistent with how they speak, I don't understand why you consider it inapropriate. (For example, I've used the pronoun "you" just then, which does not specify your gender. Do you consider that inappropriate?)

Comment: @GregoryCurrie you should be aware that for the trans community particularly, using they/them pronouns when another pronoun was specified and asked for is often done by anti-trans persons as a way to avoid accepting someone's gender but without getting in trouble with HR or the like for intentional misgendering. It's also just in general disrespectful to do that, and it's not appropriate for you to decide what someone else's pronouns should be. I should also note that pronouns are not a preference or a choice. Each person has a gender identity that is not really a choice.

Comment: @cat40 I don't buy any of that. Misgendering is disrespectful. As I said, if someone doesn't use gendered pronouns at all, with people of any gender, then they are showing trans people the same respect as they do everyone else. Pronouns are a preference. Gender is not.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Pronouns are *not* a preference. Respecting them is a basic thing you should do to everyone regardless of trans or cis status. This is the kind of thing that cisgender people don't get often because they have the privilege of their pronouns almost always being respected and guessed correctly. And since you don't buy any of that, including the part about not choosing someone's pronouns for them, you should probably do some introspection to determine if you may be unintentionally transphobic or not.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Generally the correct action if you insist on not using the correct pronouns for someone is to use their name in place of any pronoun. Here's a couple resources arguing against gender neutral pronouns for everyone as well as a guide to gender identity terms: https://www.npr.org/2021/06/02/996319297/gender-identity-pronouns-expression-guide-lgbtq#questions 
https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/voices/actually-we-should-not-all-use-they-them-pronouns/

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Finally, I'm not quite sure what your second comment actually means since you agree misgendering is disrespectful but then argue in favor of it.

Comment: @cat40 Using a gender neutral pronoun is not misgendering. We actually do it all the time. You used it above for example. No need to suggest I'm transphobic. That's rather disrespectful.

Comment: @cat40 Any article that suggests that words are violence are not worth reading. I'm with SA on this one.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie I fear I have failed to convince you to have an open mind about things like letting the trans community decide what it wants instead of the cis community forcing things upon us (and using a gender neutral pronoun when the gender is known **is** misgendering, at least for a trans person) so I will disengage from that discussion. I should also clarify that at no time did I even imply you're transphobic, but rather misguided in a way that appears transphobic externally.  I would like to know what SA is?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie there is also a thing called "non-violent communication" which is not about actual physical violence but about how to say things and argue in a manner that does not make someone feel attacked or defensive. It's a great thing for everyone to learn because it can help turn workplace conflicts and such into friendly conversations that lead to a productive compromise.

Comment: @cat40 If you think using gender neutral pronouns is misgendering, you should probably avoid using gender neutral pronouns as you did above. I have an open mind about such things, it's actually disrespectful to suggest that I have not given matters such thought. SA is Scientific American, which is composed of people of all genders.

Comment: @cat40 If you think that not saying anything about someone's gender is misgendering, then I don't think I can change you mind on that. It's an illogical stance.

Answer (score 9):

If you work in a position that primarily involves computing, the simplest thing to do is to put it in your email signature like so:

> Kind regards,
>
> ---
>
> Bbrk24 (Xe/Xem)
>
> XYZ Systems, Inc.

This conveys the information in a place they will at least occasionally notice, and a few at least will pick up on it and start using it - then the rest will likely follow, assuming they pay attention.

Of course, this is the more passive approach; it is *entirely* reasonable to politely inform your coworkers when they use "he" that you prefer "xe".

> Bbrk is working on the abc system today, and he will be working on the xyzzy system next week.
>
> > Hi! Yes, I'll be working on that system.  Just for your information, I use the "xe/xim" pronouns.  Thanks for understanding!

Something like that is perfectly appropriate in a professional workplace.  If people *do* have difficulty respecting your preferences, it might be a different conversation (with your manager and/or HR), but I'd at least start with the base assumption of professionalism without any reason to think otherwise.

Comment: So far, most of my conversations have been in person or over slack; I haven’t sent (m)any emails. Slack has a place where I can put pronouns, but I’m not sure whether people will check it or even know it exists.

Comment: @Bbrk24, I'm not sure if it depends on Slack's configuration, but in the Slack communities I've been in, if someone enters their pronouns in Slack, it displays pretty prominently on the mouse-over popup and their profile. That's something I routinely check when I meet someone new on Slack. It's at least better than not showing the information anywhere.

Comment: Adding pronouns has recently been added to MS Teams too.

Comment: If people aren't already familiar with those particular pronouns, then a bare ‘xe/xem’ may mean nothing to them; perhaps something more explicit such as ‘pronouns: xe/xem’ might be more widely understood?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It isn't that difficult because most of the time coworkers would use the default pronouns.  Even in a large company, employees might only interact with 50 or so fellow employees.  Which probably brings it down to 1 or 2 people whose pronouns might need to be remembered.  It's at the same level of difficulty as remembering how to pronounce unusual names.

Comment: @DaveG Except it's 4 pronouns required per person (though for some reason only 2 are even stated).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I agree that someone expecting you to read their mind and guess what today's pronouns are is unreasonable.  The OP says that the OP uses xe/xem for that reason.

Comment: Since many people may not be familiar with neopronouns, they may not know how to pronounce xe/xem. Is it /zi/ and /zɛm/, or /ki/ and /kɛm/, or /çi/ and /çɛm/, or ??? You may need to also include the pronunciation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sure, the CEO isn't going to remember you.  But presumably there is value in those that do work with you on a regular basis using the proper pronouns.  One can only do as much as is possible. Expecting mistakes is of course reasonable.